# Replace one property in CSS styles

Tags: javascript

I have body with style

`background: url('hereSomeImg')`

And when i do

`document.body.style.background = 'url(../img/apple_true.jpg)'`

Other styles doesn't work. Here is only background . 
How i can save them ?

Comment: `backround`? It should be `background`.

Comment: are you sure the image is where you think it is? do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: if you have css style where image is in `../img`. then when you set it in JS you need `./img` you're no longer in css file.

Comment: @blurfus i dont have errors and bg changes. I mean properties like "background-size" is strikethrough

Comment: `background` is a shorthand property, so when you set it, it implicitly resets other sub-properties (like `background-size`, `backgrpound-color`, `background-attachment` etc.) to their default values. To change only `background-image` sub-property, it's better to set it explicitly.

Comment: if background-size is shown with a strikethrough it means something else is over-writing it (i.e. another CSS style) you would need to find out which class or setting is doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could edit your code:

```
document.body.style.background = 'url("../img/apple_true.jpg")'
```

You're supposed to wrap the url in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, from what I see in your comments, you could try setting `document.body.style["background-size"]` to whatever you desire.